# How to find new open source projects on GitHub?

Tags: open-source, github

How do I track new projects on Github (are there any RSS feeds, scrapable pages or a web app to the same effect)?

On similar open-source hosting/aggregating sites:

NOTE: SourceForge has been found [distributing adware/malware with the binary installers](http://lwn.net/SubscriberLink/564250/0a106d6379c0d741/), so should not be trusted at all.

- [New file releases](http://rss.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/export/rss_sfnewsreleases)
- [New projects added](http://rss.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/export/rss2_sfnewprojects.php)
  -->

Freecode is the simplest case, but it is unfortunately rather stable and does not reflect my core interests or find new projects sufficiently fast.

Comment: Your question prompted me to look at Sourceforge for the first time in years, and I have to say I was really shocked by all the Microsoft ads.   How things have changed!

Comment: @Dmitri - what ads? :) (good to have some well-tuned blockers) I would also include codeplex etc. in the watchlist, but GitHub tends to attract more stuff nowadays.

Comment: This question might be better asked on [Webapps.se], but you might need to reword it as it currently reads a bit like a "list of X" question (the only answer you got was a link only answer).

Comment: @ChrisF - I'm going to add details on GitHub Developers' API into the question.

Comment: Hey Deer Hunter, I've removed the answer part from your question prior to migration, because... answers should be posted as answers ;) You can find it in the [revision history](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/201448/revisions) of your original question, and you can (and should) post it as an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub has a [developers' API](http://developer.github.com/v3/) which can be accessed from an unregistered user at the rate of 60 queries per hour.

To see how many queries remain, use this GET endpoint: https://api.github.com/rate_limit

To obtain the list of repositories, this GET endpoint is used: https://api.github.com/repositories

For more details on pagination (30 items per request by default) and other parameters see the [docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/).

Answer (score 0):

For github you may have a look at

http://thechangelog.com/github-trends-provides-a-rss-feed-for-most-watched-and-m/

Note: Not all feeds are working.

Comment: Ugh, sorry - "not all feeds are working" is an understatement.

Comment: Sorry for the quick reversal, must wrap my head around that site. EDIT: Not having a Fortran feed is **cruel**...